How to decode buffer data received from onAccountChange WSS method
I have the below code to get data regarding a liquidity pool -
solanaConnection.onAccountChange(
  publicKey,
  (updatedProgramInfo, context) =>
    console.log(updatedProgramInfo.data)
  "confirmed"
);

How do I decode the data in updatedProgramInfo.data from Buffer to JSON?

If it's a liquidity pool, then you'll need an SDK from the protocol developers or an IDL in order to decode the data -- be sure to look around and see what dev tools they provide!
